# Asking for input and opening a corresponding .csv file in Python

Tags: python

Python noob/newbie.

Information regarding the assignment: The company wants to know to what extent the opening and closing prices of stocks within the portfolio are correlated. The company is supplied with the daily prices for various stocks in CSV files.

(Part of) the assignment I received: "The program asks the user to enter **at least** three shares. However, if the share is already specified, or the file does not exist, a new one must be requested."

Problems:

1. Under def read_company() I have managed to get the program to ask three shares, but it needs to be "3 or more". How can my script be altered?
2. The .csv files are structured as date, open, high, low, close, adj. close, volume. I wish to obtain open and close, and forward them along with the name of the company to the module in charge of processing. I tried this under def read_stocks(company) but I got two error messages. How should I modify my code?

```
from os import path
import csv

def read_information():
    company = read_company()
    open, close = read_stocks(open, close)

    return company, open, close **### needs to send company and its open and close values to a module that is in charge of the processing part ###**


def read_company():
    companies = []

    while len(companies) < 3: **### program needs to ask for 3 OR MORE companies ###**
        company = input("Enter at least three companies.")
        if company in companies:
            print("Company already entered. Enter a new company.")
        elif not path.exists(company + '.csv'):
            print(company + " does not exist. Enter a new company.")
        else:
            companies.append(company)
    return companies ### returns list of the 3 companies ###


def read_stocks(company): **### needs to read the stocks of the companies sent by previous module ###**
    stocks = []

    with open("Company" + company + ".csv", "r", newline=" ") as csvfile: ### must read list of 3 companies and extract open and close for each of them ###
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        for row in csvreader:
            stocks.append([row[1, "open"], row[4, "close"]])
    return open, close **### needs to send open and close to a module that is in charge of the processing part ###**


read_information()
```

Error msgs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/....py", line 35, in <module>
    read_information()
  File "/Users/....py", line 6, in read_information
    open, close = read_stocks(open, close)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'open' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you want an user to supply a variable number of inputs, you need to define a *sentinel* value, which will indicate the end of the user inputs. Here is an example :

```py
fruits = []
while True:
    fruit = input("Which fruit do you like ? ")
    if fruit != "":  # sentinel check
        fruits.append(fruit)
    else:
        break
print(f"You like {len(fruits)} fruits : {', '.join(fruits)}")
```

```
Which fruit do you like ? banana
Which fruit do you like ? strawberry
Which fruit do you like ? apple
Which fruit do you like ? orange
Which fruit do you like ? 
You like 4 fruits : banana, strawberry, apple, orange
```

Here I used the empty string as sentinel, but it could be `"stop"`, or anything else.
Otherwise, you could ask for the number of inputs, then ask for each of them :

```py
fruits = []
number_of_fruits = int(input("How many fruits do you like ? "))
for i in range(number_of_fruits):
    fruit = input(f"What is your n°{i} favorite fruit ? ")
    fruits.append(fruit)
print(f"You like {len(fruits)} fruits : {', '.join(fruits)}")
```

```
How many fruits do you like ? 4
What is your n°0 favorite fruit ? banana
What is your n°1 favorite fruit ? strawberry
What is your n°2 favorite fruit ? apple
What is your n°3 favorite fruit ? orange
You like 4 fruits : banana, strawberry, apple, orange
```

---

As for your second question, you read from your file (using a `csvreader`, nice !), put the info in the `stocks` variable, why don't you return it ? It contains the info you want (the *open* and *close* values).

Also, beware `open` is a built-in function in Python, that you can (locally) redefine, so that when you do `open = ...` you will lose access (in the current scope) to that function. It is frowned upon.

Comment: Oh, I did not think of asking the amount first, and then use range! I was too focussed on coding the "no less that 3 stocks" that I didn't think of another approach.

So I can use for example "opening" instead of "open", even though the header of the values I need in the csv file says "open"?

Comment: You can name your variables whatever you like, but using standard functions' names can produce strange errors. You need to specify `row[1, "open"]` because that is how the CSV is stored, but you can call your variable another way, indeed.